# Iterating toward a specific angle on a circle

Tags: math, geometry, trigonometry

I'm building a robot vehicle that has an on-board compass.  Starting from the current orientation of the vehicle in degrees, I would like to rotate it 90 degrees in either direction, using the compass.

I'm supposing that the best way to do this is to rotate the vehicle in increments within a "while" loop and test after each rotational increment if it has moved 90 degrees.

However, while dealing with transitions between two positive points is simple, it becomes challenging with transitions that involve the transition from 0 to 360.

In other words, this code for left rotation fails for obvious reasons:

```
let startingPoint = 30 // in degrees
let endPoint = startingPoint - 90
while currentPoint > endPoint {
    rotateLeft()
}
```

Is there an equation that will enable this comparison when crossing the 360/0 boundary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check difference, not absolute value.

To find whether difference is outside 90 range, you can use formula that accounts for arbitrary angles including transitions through 0 (don't forget angles should be in radians)

```
if Cos(startingangle - currentangle) <=0 then
   absolute difference is equal or more than Pi/2 (90 degrees)
```

Here thick arrow shows (ignore axis labels or divide them by 4) `Cos` of difference of zero start angle with `+-30` degrees angles (works for any start angle)

[image]

Python demo:

```
import math
def AngleInRange(value, central, arange):
    value = math.radians(value)
    central = math.radians(central)
    arange = math.radians(arange)
    return (math.cos(value - central) >= math.cos(arange))

for a in range (100, 220, 15):  #through 180
    print(a, AngleInRange(a, 150, 45))

for a in range (-40, 40, 10):  #through 0
    print(a, AngleInRange(a, -10, 20))

100 False
115 True
130 True
145 True
160 True
175 True
190 True
205 False

-40 False
-30 True
-20 True
-10 True
0 True
10 True
20 False
30 False
```

Comment: To clarify, how is the goal of 90 degrees factored into this approach?  That is, does zero represent 90 degrees in this equation?  How would it be modified for 30 degrees?  Thanks.

Comment: Yes, zero is for +- 90 degrees. This approach might be modified ` if Cos(difference) <= Cos(30)`. Cosine value is maximal +1 for zero angle and less for other angles.

Comment: Having a bit of trouble getting this to work.  It seems like the cos(starting angle - currentangle) value never falls below around .60 as the vehicle rotates, then it goes back up to .99.  As a result, the vehicle just keeps rotating.  Any thoughts?

Comment: What values of angle differences were - in degrees and radians?

Comment: It's working pretty well now!  I dug into the compass data and realized there was an issue with how I was processing the raw data off the sensor.  I may also be dealing with some magnetic interference from the robot itself.  The formula from your original answer works for 90 degrees but I haven't gotten the formula working for an arbitrary angle by replacing 0 with Cos(arbitraryangle).  For example, when I put 30 in there, I get a rotation of about 75 degrees.  Any ideas?

Comment: Cos(30deg)=Cos(Pi/6)~0.866. When `Abs(diff = (startangle-currentangle)) becomes larger than 30, Cos(diff) becomes smaller than 0.866. I added picture

Comment: Thanks.  I'm still having trouble.  Relative to your original post, is this correct: "If Cos(startingangle - currenangle) <= (arbitraryangle)"?  It does not work for me, and I'm afraid my math is not strong enough to interpret your other help.

Comment: No, you cannot compare Cos value with angle.  But compare it with Cos(possible_angular_difference)

Comment: Sorry, that's actually what I meant and it's not working for me: "If Cos(startingangle - currenangle) <= Cos(arbitraryangle)".  When I print out values for Cos(45) for example, they are not sequential so I don't see how they could be used as a test for reaching an angle, e.g. .5, -.4, -.98, -.65, .28, .96, .75, 0.14, -.91

Comment: Just realized I've been putting an angle in degrees for Cost(arbitraryangle) - should that be in radians?  I'm testing that but it doesn't quite seem to be working.

Comment: Got it working with Cos(arbitraryangle) in radians, at least for 90 degrees and under.    Angles 90 degrees and higher end up being a shorter rotation in proportion to how high they are.  E.g. requesting a 150 degree rotation results in ~30 degrees.

Comment: Yes, trig. functions take arguments in radians - I wrote this in the answer. What's wrong with 150 degrees? Is it starting angle?

Comment: Just wanted to let you know that I think I've finally got this working!  Went through a lot of hassle calibrating and filtering my digital compass, which complicated errors to get it working, of course.  I've finally switched to using an iPhone onboard the robot to provide heading, and things are working well.  Thank you!